Mass updating Postgres rows in-place to avoid primary key index scans
I've got a large table (25M rows, 30GB) that needs to have a large amount of foreign keys set to a new table that I've just added. I've prepared a temporary table that holds the primary key ID of the main table to the appropriate ID on the secondary table, so that my tables are as such:
Main_Table: (id: uuid, ..., secondaryTableId: uuid)
Secondary_Table: (id: uuid, ...)
FK_Update_Table: (mainTableId: uuid, secondaryTableId: uuid)

There are indexes on each column detailed above, and the FK_UPDATE_TABLE is filled in with the appropriate pairings via a COPY FROM CSV. The issue is that a simple UPDATE query such as below takes too long (~5 hours):
UPDATE Main_Table 
SET "secondaryTableId" = FK_Update_Table."secondaryTableId"
FROM FK_Update_Table
WHERE Main_Table."id" = FK_Update_Table."mainTableId"

I've tried paginating this into much smaller updates as well as parallelising the update on seperate connections and these don't yield much performance improvement. Running EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers, timings) to update a single row shows that most of the time of the update (5 out of 7 seconds) comes from the FK scan. 
I'm wondering if there's any way to iterate through the Main_Table in any order to avoid the primary key index scan on that table. The FK_Update_Table is much smaller (1.5 GB) so I'm thinking I can pg_prewarm to load that entire table into memory so the index search on the FK_Update_Table will be faster. I tried using a cursor with WHERE CURRENT OF ... UPDATE to see if that would update the row in place but it hasn't provided any increase in performance. Any tips or advice on how to speed this up would be very appreciated.


Can we see your pagination code? 2) Pagination is to avoid locking the table. It is unlikely to give you a performance boost. It'll probably be slower because a sequential scan is faster than doing an index scan of every row. 3) If you only need to do it once, just let it run. By the time you get an answer it could be finished.


Can we see your index definitions? I assume you ran ANALYZE on the temp table? I'd expect a seq scan on the small table to be the optimal approach. Assuming it has many fewer records, you want the seq scan there and the index scan on the large table.

Please don't post textual details, such as explain plans, as graphics. Use consistent table names in the post and explain plan to make it easier to follow. Present the entire sequence of events. It is not clear from the post when the foreign key constraints, indexes, and updates are being performed. Consider populating the new column, creating the index CONCURRENTLY , adding the foreign key constraint using the NOT VALID option, and then running VALIDATE CONSTRAINT to minimize exclusive locks. Rows cannot be updated "in place": every update creates a new tuple.
